# error installing go debugger go-delve io timeout

Tags: go, delve

I am trying to install a go debugger from this post
https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/05/06/debugging-a-go-application-inside-a-docker-container/
and I added this line to docker file

```
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
```

but it keeps on getting a timeout error

```
 => ERROR [build-env 2/5] RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest                                                                                                   

    30.6s
------
 > [build-env 2/5] RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest:
#7 30.56 go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest: module github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv/@v/list": dial tcp 172.217.168.209:443: i/o timeout
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest]: exit code: 1
make: *** [build-func] Error 1
```

when I try to visit that url in the browser

https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv/@v/list

not found: module github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv: no matching versions for query "latest"

what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `GOPROXY="${some proxy}"`, in China you can set like `GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn"`

In Dockerfile, add this line before the `go install`:

```
ENV GOPROXY="${some proxy}"
```

If you use `https://goproxy.cn` as your `go proxy`:

```
ENV GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn"
```